# k8s controller runtime read before update

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Im using the following code inside kubebuilder controller to read before update for k8s custom resource, im checking if the object exist if yes check if need to update, if not create it , as I need to use it in several places
I want to ask:

- if there is some helper that can help me to reduce this boilarplate
  code ? something like `createOrUpdate` func
- am I doing it right ?

```
if err := r.Get(ctx, client.ObjectKey{Name: sCrName, Namespace: sCrNs}, &eCmp); err != nil {
    if apierrors.IsNotFound(err) {
        // If the object does not exist, create a new one
        if err := r.Create(ctx, &eCmp); err != nil {
            return ctrl.Result{}, err
        }
    } else {
        // If there was an error other than 'not found', return the error
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
} else {
    // If the object exists, patch it
    patch := client.MergeFrom(eCmp.DeepCopy())
    if err := r.Patch(ctx, &eCmp, patch); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
}
```

**if enverything is as recomended please let me know.**
I need also to do the stratgic merge but the code doesnt support it

I found the following
https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/controller/controllerutil#CreateOrUpdate
but I dont want it to be related to timestamp, just `if something was change -> update it` or something `doesnt exist -> create it`

**when trying to update the CR with the following code it doesnt works , any idea?**

```
// If the object exists, patch it
patch := client.MergeFrom(eCmp.DeepCopy())
if err := r.Patch(ctx, &eCmp, patch); err != nil {
    return ctrl.Result{}, err
}
```

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime#section-readme) helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu - thanks Im familiar with this docs, I dont find the answer there...

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/basics/simple_controller.html)helpful to you

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu - sorry but this is too generic and doesnt answer my qustion

Answer (score 1):

you can use the controllerutil.CreateOrUpdate() function from the sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/controller/controllerutil package to reduce boilerplate code.

use controllerutil.CreateOrUpdate() function:

```
if err := controllerutil.CreateOrUpdate(ctx, r.Client, &eCmp, func() error {
    return r.Patch(ctx, &eCmp, client.MergeFrom(eCmp.DeepCopy()))
}); err != nil {
    return ctrl.Result{}, err
}
```

strategic merge, you can add the strategic merge patch to the callback function to patch the object strategically

```
  if err := controllerutil.CreateOrUpdate(ctx, r.Client, &eCmp, func() error {
        // Create a strategic merge patch
        strategicMergePatch, err := strategicpatch.CreateTwoWayMergePatch(eCmp, &newECmp, eCmp)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        // Patch the object strategically
        return r.Patch(ctx, &eCmp, client.ConstantPatch(types.StrategicMergePatchType, strategicMergePatch))
    }); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
```

Comment: HI, thanks I tried to `strategicMergePatch, err := strategicpatch.CreateTwoWayMergePatch(eCmp, &newECmp, eCmp)` and I got design time erorr as it expects byte any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with how you've done it, you could potentially restructure it a little to reduce the if nesting.

```
err := r.Get(ctx, client.ObjectKey{Name: sCrName, Namespace: sCrNs}, &eCmp)
// Object exists, patch it
if err == nil {
    patch := client.MergeFrom(eCmp.DeepCopy())
    if err := r.Patch(ctx, &eCmpp, patch); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
    return patch, nil // Adjust appropriately
} else if apierrors.IsNotFound(err) {
    // Object does not exist, create a new one
    if err := r.Create(ctx, &eCmp); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
} 
return ctrl.Result{}, err
```

That `CreateOrUpdate` function looks like it should also do what you want. It doesn't do any comparison with a timestamp. The example on there is doing that specifically but if you look at the underlying function [controllerutil.go#L195](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/v0.14.6/pkg/controller/controllerutil/controllerutil.go#L195) you will see that there is no timestamp comparison there.

What you will need to do is either define your mutate function (a function with the patch logic) and pass that as a parameter or create an anonymous function and pass that in.

For example:

```
op, err := controllerutil.CreateOrUpdate(context.TODO(), client, object, func() error {
    
    // Your mutate logic goes in here

    return nil
})
```

If you look at the `CreateOrUpdate` function, it's essentially doing the same thing you are in your code except for the mutate (patching) of the resource.

Comment: HI, thanks, the problem is that I im tring to read the CR and modify it with new field value and update it in the cluster , when using hte following code it doesnt works, any idea? ```    patch := client.MergeFrom(eCmp.DeepCopy())
    if err := r.Patch(ctx, &eCmpp, patch); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }```